# In Pycharm, how to keep my previous runed results even after I edit the code and rerun the algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am fixing an algorithm in Pycharm so I need to modify the code a lot to see what is going on. After modifying, I rerun the code and Pycharm clear the previous result, which makes me unable to check the differences between two different versions of the code. Does anyone know how to keep all previous results even after I rerun the algorithm in Pycharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that `Run` tab?

[image]

You can right-click on the tab and select `Pin tab`. Now that tab is pinned. If you re-run the code a new tab should open up to show the result.And you can switch between the tabs to compare the results.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have all the results in the same tab?

Comment: Not that I know of. Each tab seems to be for a single run only.